# color swatches not displaying in details page

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, theme, swatches

I have created configurable swatches for color attribute in my custom theme.The color swatch is displayed in product list page. But it is not displaying in product details page.Kindly anyone guide me to solve my issue.

Comment: Just to be sure, it's Magento 1.9, right?

Comment: yes. It is magento 1.9.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem was in stylesheet. It was like,

```
.product-options dl:first-child: display: none !important;
```

Now I changed it to

```
.product-options dl:first-child: display: block !important;
```

Answer (score 2):

If the custom theme is not built upon `rwd/default`, configurable swatches of Magento will not work with it. Even if it is, it seems to override the product page templates without adding the configurable swatches feature.

You have several options:

- There is a free extension that helps you to make it compatible with other themes, you can give it a try: https://github.com/tmhub/catalog-configurable-swatches
- Ask theme vendor for support / complain
- Use a different solution that's independent of themes. I recommend Easylife Switcher by @Marius: https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher

Comment: Yea My custom theme is built upon rwd.